# A function whose absolute value is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

I'm looking for a function f which is not Lebesgue integrable but |f| is integrable or can we say that such function does not exist?

Comment: Try setting things up so that $|f|$ is a constant function with $f$ nonmeasurable.

Comment: One should note that the question is more about if there exists a function such that $f$ is not lebesgue measurable but $|f|$ is, since provided $f$ being measurable, the conditions $f$ integrable and $|f|$ integrable are equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A\subset [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set. Then $[0,1]-A$ is also non-measurable. Define 
$$f(x)=\chi_A-\chi_{[0,1]-A}$$
Then you may verify that $f$ satisfies the condition you desire.